# Returning Dictionary<FileHash, string[]> from Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, file, duplicates

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to get a list of duplicate files using their hashes to identify the list of files associated with the hashes.

I have this below:

```
Dictionary<FileHash, string[]> FindDuplicateFiles(string searchFolder)
{
    Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, "*.*")
        .Select(
            f => new
                     {
                         FileName = f,
                         FileHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new SHA1Managed()
                                                                .ComputeHash(new FileStream(f,
                                                                                            FileMode.
                                                                                                OpenOrCreate,
                                                                                            FileAccess.Read)))
                     })
        .GroupBy(f => f.FileHash)
        .Select(g => new
                         {
                             FileHash = g.Key,
                             Files = g.Select(z => z.FileName).ToList()
                         })
        .GroupBy(f => f.FileHash)
        .Select(g => new {FileHash = g.Key, Files = g.Select(z => z.Files).ToArray()});
```

It compiles fine, but I'm just curious whether there's even a way to manipulate the results to return a Dictionary.

Any suggestions, alternatives, critiques would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles if you switched to C#4 already.

Comment: Those last lines are duplicates, is that on purpose? Better edit.

Comment: Note that you cannot decode any random byte sequence (such as a SHA-1 hash) into an string. **Not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already an extension method which will do this. Just stick this at the end of your existing query:

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.FileHash, x => x.Files);
```

However: using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to convert *arbitrary binary data* into a string is a really bad idea. Use `Convert.ToBase64String` instead. The hash is *not* a UTF-8 encoded string, so don't treat it as one.

You're also grouping by hash twice, which I suspect isn't really what you want to do.

Alternatively, remove the previous `GroupBy` calls and use a `Lookup` instead:

```
var query = Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, "*.*")
                     .Select(f => new {
                         FileName = f,
                         FileHash = Convert.ToBase64String(
                             new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(...))
                        })
                     .ToLookup(x => x.FileHash, x => x.FileName);
```

That will give you a `Lookup<string, string>`, which is basically the files grouped by hash.

One further thing to note: I suspect you'll be leaving file streams open with this method. I suggest you write a small separate method to compute the hash of a file based on its name, but making sure you close the stream (with a `using` statement in the normal way). This will also end up making your query simpler - something along the lines of:

```
var query = Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder)
                     .ToLookup(x => ComputeHash(x));
```

It's hard to simplify it much further than that :)

Comment: Yes, this seems like a much better approach. A lot cleaner and easier for someone reading it to figure out what I'm tryng to do. I think I also need to read up a little bit on hashing algorithm do's and dont's. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method to IEnumerable<_> called toDictionary which converts a sequence of key value pairs to dictionary. Might raise exception on duplicate keys.

Why do you need the second GroupBy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) to collect a LINQ query into a dictionary:

```
var sha1 = new SHA1Managed();

Dictionary<string, string[]> result =
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(searchFolder)
        .GroupBy(file => Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(...)))
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
```

Some remarks:

- Don't assume that a random byte sequence (such  as a SHA-1 hash) is a valid UTF-8 string.
- Consider using [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) instead of Directory.GetFiles.
- Don't forget to close the FileStream after computing the SHA-1 hash.
- Afaik it's possible to reuse a SHA1Managed, so you don't need to create a new one for each file.